# Logit model notation

Tags: regression, econometrics, random-effects-model, logit, notation

I am running a regression of local area unemployment on health outcomes. Initially I had intended to make use of a linear model. But now I am going to make use of a random effects estimator in a logit model. I was able to describe the notation for my linear model quite easily, but I really don't know what this models notation should look like now that it is a logit random effects model.

I attach my initial linear model as below where:

[image]

As I mentioned, I wish to investigate the impacts of the local area unemployment rate on health outcomes and health behaviours in a logit model which controls for individual-specific effects as I am using panel data. I can do all of the statistics to make this happen, I just find myself confused as to how the notation which describes what I am doing should look in a logit random effects model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could describe your model as follows:

${y_{it}=
\begin{cases}
1, \quad \text{if}\ x'_{it}\beta + \alpha_i > 0,\\
0, \quad \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}}$

where $\alpha_i$ denotes the random effect.

This implies the following probabilities of observing a one- or a zero-valued dependent variable
$\Pr[y_{it} = 1\mid x_{it}] = \int_\alpha \frac{\exp(x'_{it}\beta + \alpha)}{1+\exp(x'_{it}\beta + \alpha)}dF(\alpha)$

$\Pr[y_{it} = 0\mid x_{it}] = \int_\alpha \frac{1}{1+\exp(x'_{it}\beta + \alpha)}dF(\alpha)$